# How to delay next action in sequence until after runBlock completes? (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

The `duration` property for `moveTo` isn't followed when inside a `runBlock`, allowing the subsequent action in a sequence to get executed immediately when it should only get executed after `duration` seconds.

Code A (sequence properly executed):

```
let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)

itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), moveAction, SKAction.runBlock {
    itemB.removeFromParent()
}]))
```

Code B (sequence not properly executed):

```
let badMoveAction = SKAction.runBlock {
    let realDest = CGPointMake(itemA.position.x, itemA.position.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: 2.0)
    itemB.runAction(moveAction)
}

itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), badMoveAction, SKAction.runBlock {
    itemB.removeFromParent()
}]))
```

In `Code A`, `itemB` gets removed after the `moveAction` completes (about 2 seconds). This is the correct sequence.

In `Code B`, `itemB` gets removed before `badMoveAction` finishes, meaning `itemB` never moves from its original position. It's as if the duration property isn't honored in `Code B`.

How can we move `itemB` as in `Code B` but ensure the next action in the sequence doesn't start until `badMoveAction` completes?

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[`runBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) of `SKAction` creates action with zero duration and it takes place instantaneously. So in `Code B` it will start executing first action and return immediately to start next action in sequence.

If you want to create your own action with duration you can use [`customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:). Otherwise here `Code A` is perfectly fine(if you want to use move action only).

Also you can use [`SKAction.removeFromParent()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/removeFromParent) to remove `itemB` instead of:

```
SKAction.runBlock {
itemB.removeFromParent()
}
```

**Other solution:**

As `runBlock` executes immediately you can add `waitForDuration` action before removing node.(add after runBlock with duration equal to runBlock)

```
itemB.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5),
badMoveAction, SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
```

But this can be achieved using [`customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:).

If you want both action(move, remove node) should occur simultaneously then you can also use `group` in SKAction.